# In LDAP, do we really need to register the custom attribute with IANA to get a OID

Tags: ldap, oid, iana

What is the problem in using a self-generated OID? I believe it only has to be unique across the system right? And I am only using a single LDAP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "problem" with using a self-generated OID for your **internal purposes**. Modern, professional-quality LDAP directory servers provide a mechanism for using text in place of OIDs, or some other mechanism for auto-generating OIDs. It is perfectly acceptable to use the self-generated OIDs as long as the creator does not plan to ever publish those OIDs without registration - which could create a conflict with existing published OIDs.

Comment: Thanks, that's the confirmation I wanted.